# What boxing matches were the fights in Rocky based on?

Tags: rocky, rocky-iii, rocky-iv, rocky-ii

I have heard that the major fights in the first 4 Rocky films are based on actual historic boxing matches.

Is this true?

And if it is, can someone tell me which boxing matches?

Comment: Please include information regarding where you heard this.

Comment: pretty much word of mouth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is YES and NO.  ***Rocky* and *Rocky III*** both contain inspirations from the life of [Chuck Wepner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Wepner). ***Rocky II* and *Rocky IV* do NOT contain any inspirations from the life of Wepner.**

Chuck Wepner was the original inspiration for the original [*Rocky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky) movie from 1976 according to Sylvester Stallone.  Stallone had just finished watching a boxing match between [Muhammad Ali and Chuck Wepner](http://www.cleveland.com/entertainment/index.ssf/2015/03/muhammad_ali_vs_chuck_wepner_t.html).  Immediately after watching the match, Stallone [wrote](http://espn.go.com/boxing/story/_/page/IamChuckWepner/chuck-wepner-recognized-rocky-fame) the script for *Rocky*.

> At a theater in Los Angeles, struggling actor Sylvester Stallone
>   watched the Ali-Wepner fight and promptly went home and banged out the
>   script for a little movie called "Rocky." It wasn't based on a true
>   story -- not directly. But it was inspired by and borrowed heavily
>   from a true story. By the time the movie was released on Dec. 3, 1976,
>   word had spread that Wepner was Stallone's muse, and Wepner basked in
>   the glory of hearing his first name chanted in the New York theater
>   where he watched the film.

For the movie *[Rocky III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_III)*, there is a scene where Rocky Balboa has a match with "Thunderlips" played by Hulk Hogan.  This is billed as a friendly match done for [charity](http://rocky.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderlips).

Chuck Wepner fought Professional wrestler, [Andre the Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_the_Giant) on June 25, 1976.  This match, like the Balboa vs. Thunderlips match in *Rocky III* was nothing but a publicity stunt.  The [Wepner vs. Andre the Giant](http://www.cagepotato.com/reliving-chuck-wepner-vs-andre-the-giant-the-great-american-freakshow-we-somehow-forgot/) match is basically re-created for *Rocky III*.

> For better or for worse, Chuck Wepner vs. Andre the Giant was one of
>   the first mainstream American mixed rules bouts. Whether or not you
>   can still sit through it today depends on whether or not you
>   appreciate oldschool professional wrestling, but odds are good that if
>   you’re a cinema buff, you have an appreciation for Stallone’s
>   recreation of it.

Chuck Wepner and Sylvester Stallone have had an interesting relationship.  Wepner actually sued Stallone for royalties from the Rocky franchise stating that he had never received any compensation for Stallone using his story as the inspiration for the franchise.

> In 2003, Wepner sued Stallone for cashing in on his life story and
>   never sharing a dime with "the real Rocky." Stallone settled with
>   Wepner for an undisclosed amount.

Comment: was the fight in Rocky 4 between Stallone and Lundgren based on the Rumble in the Jungle (Ali vs Foreman)? in both fights George Foreman/Dolph Lundgren was expected to not only win but actually end up killing their opponent - Ali won the match by employing the now famous rope-a-dope technique, and Stallone does something similar, letting Dolph beat the hell out of him, knackering Dolph out - before coming through in a later round... I always thought there might be a possibility that Rocky 4's last fight scene was inspired by the Rumble in the Jungle?

Comment: @Jimmery Yeah, but that is how most of Rocky's fights were.  That's how his fight with Apollo Creed was in Rocky II and his fight with Clubber Lang in Rocky III.  He lets them beat him up until he gets angry and then he ends up winning the fights.  So, I don't know if I would consider the fight between him and Drago in Rocky IV a unique one.

Comment: you make a good point!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know all the details buts it's fairly well accepted round the rumor mill that Chuck Wepner is an influence. He had a 15 round fight with Ali that was brutal. Apparently this inspired part of the story for Rocky. this has been the general guide since the movie first came out. Here is a relatively (2011) recent post about it. [ALi v Chuck, Rocky story.](http://espn.go.com/boxing/story/_/page/IamChuckWepner/chuck-wepner-recognized-rocky-fame)

Answer (score 1):

I Was just watching the fight  Ali vs Bonavena and there are too many coincidences in  Bonavena boxing and Rocky such the upper cut or the way that he keep moving event getting a big punch. also the fact that this guy came from Argentina and Rocky supposed to have "Italian blood". I know Argentina and Italy are different , but both are some way alike .

Answer (score 1):

I kinda feel like the plot of Rocky III was sorta inspired by the rivalry between Sugar Ray Leonard and Roberto Duran, and even predicted the rise of Mike Tyson. Rocky, the champion, takes on contender Clubber Lang and loses. But Rocky, training in a new method to make him faster and more agile, returns to not only beat Lang but humiliates him with his blinding-fast speed. The first two Leonard/Duran fights occur in similar fashion, with Leonard losing the title to Duran, only to come back faster and more agile in the rematch, defeating Duran in embarrassing fashion in the famed "No Mas Fight". Clubber Lang could be seen as a precursor to real life boxing bruiser Mike Tyson, who often used sheer strength and aggressiveness to defeat his opponents in a very similar was to Lang, even though Tyson didn't rise to promeninece until a number of years after Rocky III was released in theaters.

Comment: great answer! i feel like the writers behind the Rocky films did take inspiration from actual fights, and this is a great example that supports that! here is the wiki on that fight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Ray_Leonard_vs._Roberto_Dur%C3%A1n_II